OPLS regression
I'm using OPLS regression to see the effects of diversity indexes on carbon stock.
Previously I was using linear mixed model, but there is a huge collinearity in my predictors, so I decided to use OPLS, however, I'm not sure how to deal with the fact of a "random effect", that in LMM I used "area" as random effect.
Is there any approach to deal with it, or in the OPLS regression it does not matter?
Thanks
I was studying about the way OPLS works, and I guess that it is not a problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
